# Need privileges to break inheritance

Tags: event-receivers, sandbox-solution, runwithelevatedprivileges

Idea is that inside an `ItemAdded` event receiver in a sandboxed solution (SharePoint Online) I want to set permissions on the item, which requires privileges that the user should not have on the list.
I see that I cannot use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` inside sandbox.

As long as inside a SharePoint 2013 Workflow one has the App Step, there should be a way to run with elevated privileges inside an event receiver also, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SandBox solution this is not possible.

You should do this using a Workflow using AppStep.

Comment: I accepted Amal's answer as it literally answers my question, although I expect to see alternative solutions. I am testing now giving full permissions to the Workflow (as an app) and assigning permissions with REST calls. I update with my results.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to solve this was in an Item Updated event receiver and with the workflow updating the item from an App Step.

Chose this because setting permissions in SharePoint Designer Workflow (2013) using REST takes too many steps.